# Why should I use UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, uiapplicationdelegate

I wonder why should I use UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey in only didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ?  It's not needed when I use didReceiveRemoteNotification. I can understand how to get push notification and handle it, but how to get push info is difference between didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and didReceiveRemoteNotification. I want to know the deep reason.

Answer (score 4):

The options passed to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` can include more than just push remote notification data.  A partial list, off the top of my head:

- remote notification data
- local notification data
- URL used to open app from a link or another app

The specific delegate methods for those activities are invoked if the app is already running*.  If the app is being launched due to one of those mechanisms, the relevant data is passed in `options`.  The keys are used to tell you which kind of event triggered the launch and which kind of data is in `options`.

*Handling background processing of remote notifications is a special case.  Even if the app is being launched to handle them, the specific delegate method is called.

Comment: Hi, Avi, thank you for the information. I could understand why there is UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey to get data from remote notification. There are 3 types of data pattern, so key is needed to decide which types of push data apps get.